# Book recommendation on transformational plane geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

A couple of days ago I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_geometry) article and found the idea of proving theorems in plane geometry only by transformations fascinating as it offers an even more visual approach to geometry. So the question is whether you guys know of any books which develop geometry using this theory. I have some knowledge of axiomatic plane geometry and precalculus, but that is it.

Comment: See ["Geometry", by Brannan, Esplen and Gray](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/geometry-2nd-edition).

Comment: Do you happen to know whether it requires knowledge of linear algebra or calculus ( I havent studied those subjects yet)

Comment: Very basic knowledge of linear algebra, and what is needed is covered in an Appendix.